# Collapsible table change chevron icon on click

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a table which contains hidden details for each row. Table rows are made with Bootstrap accordion.
Accordion rows and hidden details are working fine but the JS that changes the chevron icon when toggling [collapsed/expanded] is not working properly. It should change the chevron icon just on the clicked row but currently it changes the chevron icon for all rows.

I have read some related posts regarding my question and have tried them all but I'm unable to get it working. What I'm missing?

There is a **[Bootply Demo here](http://www.bootply.com/22ubptT24i)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-wrapper">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i> Maintenance Work Requests <small>List</small></h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "MaintWORequests", null)"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active">Listado de Solicitudes</li>
                </ol>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Maintenance Work Requests</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="solicitudes" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped tablesorter" style="vertical-align:middle; border-collapse:collapse">
                            <thead>                                        
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center"></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center"># <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center">Títle <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center">Component<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center">Created <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center">Type<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center">Approved By<i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th class="header" style="text-align:center">Status <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>                                   


                                 <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1" class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">3325</td>
                                    <td>Trabajo sobre Sistema Eléctrico</td>
                                    <td>710.100.00.00 - Sistema Eléctrico</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">2014/05/24</td>
                                    <td><p class="text-info" style="text-align:center"><b>Solicitud</b></p></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"></td>
                                    <td class="info" style="text-align:center"><span class="label label-primary" style="font-size:small">Creada&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   <td colspan="8" class="hiddenRow">
                                            <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="1"> 
                                                <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="margin:0px;">
                                                    <h4><i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Detalles</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Details for row #1
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                                  

                                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#2" class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor:pointer">
                                   <td style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">3324</td>
                                    <td>AVERIA: Correa transmisión Motor Aux</td>
                                    <td>620.100.20.00 - Transmisión</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">2014/05/01</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><p class="text-danger"><b>Avería</b></p></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">Supervisor Mantenimiento</td>
                                    <td class="success" style="text-align:center"><span class="label label-success" style="font-size:small">Aceptada&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   <td colspan="8" class="hiddenRow">
                                            <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="2"> 
                                                <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="margin:0px;">
                                                    <h4><i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Detalles</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Details for row #2
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                                            
                                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#3" class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor:pointer">
                                   <td style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">3327</td>
                                    <td>Revisión Panel Eléctrico</td>
                                    <td>710.100.60.10 - Panel Nº 1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">2014/04/27</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><p class="text-info"><b>Solicitud</b></p></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"></td>
                                    <td class="warning" style="text-align:center"><span class="label label-warning" style="font-size:small">Revisión&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   <td colspan="8" class="hiddenRow">
                                            <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="3"> 
                                                <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="margin:0px;">
                                                    <h4><i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Detalles</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Details for row #3
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#4" class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor:pointer">
                                   <td style="text-align:center"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">3323</td>
                                    <td>Chequeo cableado catenaria</td>
                                    <td>320.200.60.30 - Catenaria</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">2014/04/26</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"><p class="text-info"><b>Solicitud</b></p></td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center"></td>
                                    <td class="danger" style="text-align:center"><span class="label label-danger" style="font-size:small">Rechazada&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i></span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   <td colspan="8" class="hiddenRow">
                                            <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="4"> 
                                                <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info" style="margin:0px;">
                                                    <h4><i class="fa fa-info"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Detalles</h4>
                                                    <p>
                                                        Details for row #4
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
    <div>
        <p><button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" index",="" "maintworequests",="" null)';return="" false;"="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="font-size: 25px"><i class="fa fa-mail-reply"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Volver</button></p>   
    </div>
</div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->
```

**JS**

```
$('tr').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".fa-plus-square").removeClass("fa-plus-square").addClass("fa-minus-square");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".fa-minus-square").removeClass("fa-minus-square").addClass("fa-plus-square");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `.parent()` to `.prev()` or `.prev('tr')`

```
  $('tr').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).prev('tr').find(".fa-plus-square").removeClass("fa-plus-square").addClass("fa-minus-square");
  }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).prev('tr').find(".fa-minus-square").removeClass("fa-minus-square").addClass("fa-plus-square");
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(".accordion-toggle").on("click", function () {
  if($(this).find(".fa").hasClass("fa-plus-square")) {
    $(this).find(".fa").removeClass("fa-plus-square").addClass("fa-minus-square");
  } else {
    $(this).find(".fa").removeClass("fa-minus-square").addClass("fa-plus-square");
  }
});
```